# What is the correct version of the Gronwall lemma? Can the sign of u(t) be variable?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-inequality

In https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Gronwall_lemma the various forms of the Grönwall lemma in integral form are stated for NON NEGATIVE function $\phi$

And this coincides with what is written my lecture notes. However the proof we made did not used the fact that u(t) (that is $\phi$ in the above article) should be positive, so I am suspicious it is not required. Still, we used the Gronwall lemma to prove the continuous dependence of the solution of a Cauchy problem on the initial value, but in that case the u(t) that we applied the lemma to was a norm of some function so it was clearly nonnegative, but still this doesn't say if it works for variable-sign functions

In fact the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_for_continuous_functions  highlights no assumptions are made on the sign of the function u(t) and so does not use it in the proof.

**So, what is the correct version? Can the sign of u(t) be variable?  If you have an example were the lemma is applied to a variable-sign function that may help, too.**
Do you have any reference of a proof  requiring  non negative u(t) as hypothesis and where that fact is clearly used ?

Comment: You're right, the sign of $u$ is irrelevant in that version of the lemma (the one you linked to on Wikipedia, or Theorem 3 on Planet Math).

Comment: @HansLundmark On encyvlopedia of Math you mean? theorem 3 is stated with the hypothesis of  non negative $\phi$ as well

Comment: Yes, of course, that's what I meant! Sorry. Even though they state Thm 3 with the assumption that $\phi \ge 0$, it's true without that assumption, as the proof on Wikipedia shows. (And the sign of $B$ is also irrelevant.)